# Chef registry_key resource giving unexpected result in inspec test

Tags: chef-infra

Hi I am using registry key resource of chef inspec .
For parent folder code is working fine but for children folder its not.
Below code:

```
describe registry_key('HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server') do
  it { should exist } #working
end

describe registry_key('HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\SQLNCLI11\CurrentVersion') do  
  it { should exist } #not working
end

describe registry_key('HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\SqlCmdLnUtils\CurrentVersion') do
  it { should exist } # not working
end
```

Comment: Please include what output you do get and why you think the output is wrong.

Comment: describe registry_key('HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server') do
  it { should exist } #working
end  #test is pasing but                                                                                                         describe registry_key('HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\SqlCmdLnUtils\CurrentVersion') do
  it { should exist } # not working
end  #test is failing

Comment: Yes you already said that by why do you think that isn't correct? How are you checking that those keys do exist?

Comment: Bu using regedit.exe I am verifying. I am going to both location using regedit and able to see keys are exist but chef inspec registry_key resource just passing first test not all three.